# Jbutton doesn't work how it should

Tags: jbutton, properties-file

I have a button called 'btnSearch' and a text field called 'textFieldSearch'.
I have  a properties file which the user can search to get a key from. If the key exists I want it to return the key from the file and display it with its value yet at the moment it doesn't do it when I thought what I have should work. Thanks to anyone who can help!

//code for button

```
      JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
      btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            //find selected command

            String key_name = textFieldSearch.getText();
            if(textFieldSearch.getText().equals(properties.getProperty(key_name)))
            {
                System.out.println("hurrah");
            }


        }
    });
    panelSearch.add(btnSearch, "cell 6 3");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the Property with the name of `key_name`, but then you are comparing that value against the value `key_name`. Instead you should ask the Property Object if it has a property `key_name`, if it returns `null` then there is no such property or the value as a String.

Comment: I see so I would effectively need to change this: (properties.getProperty(key_name))) ? 

Thanks for the help! :)